# Использование модулей в импортрованных модулях

Tags: python, модули

У меня есть `main.py` и `app.py`. В `main.py` я импортирую `app.py`. Но у меня обе программы используют модуль `requests`. `app.py` представляет из себя только один класс, где я в `__init__()` делаю `self.r = requests`. То же самое и в `main.py`.

Как лучше поступить, в оба моих модуля импортировать `requests` или импортировать только в `main.py` и оттуда "пихать" в мой `app.py`?

Я хотел бы использовать второй вариант, но получается какая-то шляпа :(

Comment: А почему вы хотите второй вариант? И зачем вам self.r?

Comment: @andreymal , r - имя переменной, self - класс ссылается сам на себя, мне нужно это, чтобы использовать переменную r в других функциях этого класса

Comment: Зачем вам переменная r, если вы можете использовать просто requests?

Comment: @andreymal Вторйо вариант, потому что меня напрягает, когда импортируется одно и то же несколько раз по сути в одной проге, но разных модулях

Comment: Почему вас это напрягает? Вы какой-то странный

Comment: @andreymal Сам не знаю, я учусь еще только

Comment: @andreymal Я подумал, что расход памяти можно сократить, если я импортирую requests тольк один раз для двух задач

Comment: Модуль загружается в память ровно один раз независимо от числа импортов

Comment: @andreymal Понял, раньше не знал, спасибо за помощь